# Invalid page response when I hit multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I recieve an image instead of page contents when i hit a page multiple times.Application is devloped in MVC and running under IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your hosts file under "c:\Windows\System32\drivers\" 
If your site is using CDN then often the request on page gets pending